# CMake error: found relative path while evaluating include directories of

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to understand why CMake is complaining in a given situation.

I have module A depending on module B which depends on module C.

Module C is a subdir of module B, and the pertinent parts of each module's CMakeLists.txt are as shown here:

module A does:

```
add_library(A STATIC "")

target_include_directories(A PRIVATE 
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:B,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)
```

module B does:

```
add_library(B static "")

set(some_dirs
  C
)

foreach(DIR ${some_dirs})
  add_subdirectory(${DIR})
  target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC ${DIR})
endforeach(DIR)
```

module C does:

```
add_library(C STATIC "")

target_include_directories(C
  PUBLIC 
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:OtherLib,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
  PRIVATE
)
```

There is an executable that links against module A.

The reason for the use of TARGET_PROPERTY:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is that I am moving a large project with a lot of circular dependencies from a monolithic executable to one with distinct libraries.  My initial effort is just to create the modules, then later to break the circular dependencies.  So in this example, rather than `target_link_libraries` on the dependency, I use `target_include_directories` with the property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES for the dependencies.  I hope that makes sense.

I get an error with the above situation that includes:

```
Configuring done
Failed to parse JSON from CMake server.
Failed to parse JSON from CMake server.
CMake Error in A/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of
  "A":
```

followed by some garbage characters and some more "Failed to parse JSON from CMake server lines.

However, when I modify module C to the following:

```
add_library(C STATIC "")

target_include_directories(C
  PUBLIC 
  PRIVATE
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:OtherLib,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)
```

The generation errors go away.

*OR* 
If I leave module C as it was originally, but change module B to this (i.e. not link against C):

```
add_library(B static "")

set(some_dirs
  C
)

foreach(DIR ${some_dirs})
  add_subdirectory(${DIR})
#  target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC ${DIR})
endforeach(DIR)
```

and A to this:

```
add_library(A STATIC "")

target_include_directories(A PRIVATE 
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:B,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:C,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)
```

Then the generation errors also go away.

I don't quite understand why CMake thinks there are relative paths when module C uses PUBLIC vs PRIVATE inclusion.  I also don't understand why the problem goes away when I remove C as a dependency of B.  I do understand that IMPORTED targets can't have relative paths, but none of my targets are IMPORTED, since they are all defined within the same project.

Comment: As far as I understand CMake documentation, every path in  `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property is **absolute**. [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/include_directories.html) for `include_directories` explicitely says, that relative paths passed to it are interpreted as relative to current source directory. I think, the same is true for `target_include_directories` command. When use generator expressions, you need to be sure that they give **absolute paths** (it is noted for some CMake commands).

Comment: Also note, that `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property actually lists "private" directories (it is [filled](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_include_directories.html) from `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` keywords). You probably want to read `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property, which is filled from `INTERFACE` and `PUBLIC` keywords.

Comment: Thanks, Tsyvarev.  I had read the part that described how both Public and Private includes populate the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property.  The documentation is pretty good, but so far I've found nothing to explain this case.

Comment: By "read `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property" I meant to **use** this property **in the code** (instead of `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` one which is currently used). Using generator expression `$<TARGET_PROPERTY>` can be interpreted as *reading* the property, this is why I have refered to it as a "read".

Comment: That is good advice.  I fear that what I am doing by using plain INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES is dragging along a lot of extra dependencies and over-including.

Comment: Over the course of the day, my problems have gone away after conversion from property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES to INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.

If you want to write an "answer" I will mark it as the accepted one.